# Gradient Overlay Doesn't Match Image Size in HorizontalPager

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on a project where I'm using a `HorizontalPager` to slide through a series of images. Each image has a gradient overlay applied using a Box element with a gradient brush. The issue I'm facing is that the gradient overlay doesn't match the image size when sliding through the images. I suspect it's related to the scaling applied to the image, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) { page ->
    val isAnimating = pagerState.settledPage == page
    ImageItem(enableAnimation = isAnimating)

}


@Composable
fun ImageItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enableAnimation: Boolean = false,
    backgroundUrl: String = "https://picsum.photos/1200",
    backgroundGradient: Brush = Brush.linearGradient(
        listOf(
            DarkGray.copy(alpha = 0.0f), Black.copy(alpha = 0.8f)
        )
    )
) {

    val scaleValue = if (enableAnimation) 1.1f else 1.0f
    var scale by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(1.1f) }
    var startAnimation by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    if (enableAnimation && startAnimation) {
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = backgroundUrl) {
            val translationAnimationSpec = tween<Float>(
                durationMillis = 2700,
                easing = FastOutLinearInEasing
            )
            animate(
                initialValue = 1.1f,
                targetValue = 1.0f,
                animationSpec = translationAnimationSpec
            ) { value: Float, _: Float ->
                scale = value
            }
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .fillMaxHeight()
    ) {
        AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                .data(backgroundUrl)
                .crossfade(true).scale(Scale.FILL).build(),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
                .scale(scale),
            filterQuality = FilterQuality.High,
            onSuccess = {
                startAnimation = true
            },
            placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.full_screen)
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(brush = backgroundGradient)
                .matchParentSize()
                .scale(scale)
        )
    }
}
```

I've tried scaling both the gradient overlay `Box` and the image, but the issue still persists. How can I ensure that the gradient overlay matches the image size when sliding through the images?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this happens because of `Modifier.scale`.

By default, Compose does not crop images to bounds. And the scale modifier doesn't affect the layout of the view, it just changes how the view is drawn.

If you use it with a value higher than 1, the content will be drawn outside the bounds - that's what you see here.

The easiest way to fix this is to clip the view - apply `Modifier.clip(RectangleShape)`. Note that it should be applied before `Modifier.scale`, otherwise it will affect the scaled size, and so won't have any effect.

```
modifier = Modifier
    .matchParentSize()
    .clip(RectangleShape)
    .scale(scale)
```